# Feasibility to select choices received from the web service and display only the selected choices to the end user using SurveyJS Survey Creater?

Tags: angular, surveyjs

Functionality required

1. Survey creator to view choices received from web service.
2. Survey creator should be able to select choices received from the web service.
3. Only the selected choices by the survey creator are to be visible for the end user to select.